# array of swing objects returns null pointer exception

Tags: java, arrays, swing, nullpointerexception

here is my snippet.It returns a null pointer exception..jlabel1 is already set and working

```
JLabel j[]=new JLabel[10];
i=0;    
j[i]=new JLabel();
j[i].setText("1");
this.add(j[i]);
```

Edit (from the comments)

```
JLabel j[]=new JLabel[50]; 
try { 
  Rectangle bounds = jLabel1.getBounds(); 
  j[i].setText("1"); 
  this.add(j[i]); 
  j[i].setBounds(jLabel1.getX(),jLabel1.getY()+50 ,jLabel1.getHeight(),jLabel1.getWidth()); } catch(Exception e) { 
  System.out.println(e.toString()); 
}
```

Comment: Where is this code located? Which method/function?

Comment: There's no jlabel1 in your question and where is jlabel1 "already set and working"

Comment: For better understanding exception print a stacktrace.

Comment: @HarshitSharaff Don't you know that try/catch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot the

```
j[i] = new JLabel();
```

in the snippet you posted in the comments (although it was included in your question).

A `NullPointerException` is typically easy to debug as you just have to follow the stack trace to discover what exactly is `null`. When in doubt, you just place a breakpoint on that line and use a debugger.

To obtain the stacktrace, you can use `e.printStackTrace()` or simply remove the `try catch` block (as it is bad practice to simply have a `try catch` block for all exceptions)

Answer (score 3):

Comments are too short. Try to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

This seems to work for me:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    protected void initUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Test JLabel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        class TestPanel extends JPanel {
            int i;

            public TestPanel() {
                JLabel j[] = new JLabel[10];
                i = 0;
                j[i] = new JLabel();
                j[i].setText("1");
                this.add(j[i]);
            }
        }
        frame.add(new TestPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: JLabel j[]=new JLabel[50];
        try
        {
                Rectangle bounds = jLabel1.getBounds();
                j[i].setText("1");
                this.add(j[i]);
               j[i].setBounds(jLabel1.getX(),jLabel1.getY()+50 ,jLabel1.getHeight(),jLabel1.getWidth());
        }
       catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

This snippet gives java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @HarshitSharaff Hard to tell without a complete example (SS **C** CE). Either jLabel1 is null or j[i] is. Without context, we can't help you much more. We are not wild guessing gurus.